# Where is the first online reference to the "HeartBleed" bug?

Tags: openssl, heartbleed

From what I know, the HeartBleed bug seems to occur around 15 hours ago. As per [heartbleed.com](http://heartbleed.com/), the HeartBleed bug was independently discovered by a team of security engineers at Codenomicon.

How did the public came to know about the news?

Where is the first online reference to the "HeartBleed" bug?

Comment: Is knowing the first online reference helping you solve a problem? Or is this just a trivia question?

Comment: There is some ongoing debate on the Cloudflare blog about whether responsible disclosure was adhered to for this vulnerability. Maybe that is at the root of this question.

Comment: @Byte56, Is how the vulnerability info disseminated not a security question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hackernews user [eastdakota](https://news.ycombinator.com/user?id=eastdakota) (probably Matthew Prince) is the CEO and co-founder of CloudFlare (according to the HN bio) and [has](http://blog.cloudflare.com/staying-ahead-of-openssl-vulnerabilities#comment-1323081581) [publicly stated that](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7549986):

> One of the individuals who discovered the [Heartbleed] bug contacted
>   us as a large provider of SSL termination services. We were asked not
>   to further disclose the details until it was officially patched and
>   announced by OpenSSL. The official announcement occurred today after
>   which we [put up a post](http://blog.cloudflare.com/staying-ahead-of-openssl-vulnerabilities) to let our customers know that they were
>   protected.

[And](http://blog.cloudflare.com/staying-ahead-of-openssl-vulnerabilities#comment-1323083799):

> ...we held the post informing our customers that they were protected
>   from the bug **until after it was officially announced by the
>   organizations that had discovered it as well as by OpenSSL**

And [also](http://blog.cloudflare.com/staying-ahead-of-openssl-vulnerabilities#comment-1323138852):

> The bug was discovered by a researcher at Google and three engineers
>   at Codenomicon.

[Credits](https://www.cert.fi/en/reports/2014/vulnerability788210.html):

> The vulnerability was first reported to OpenSSL by Neel Mehta from
>   Google Security. Matti Kamunen, Antti Karjalainen and Riku Hietamäki
>   from Codenomicon Oy reported the vulnerability to NCSC-FI, who
>   reported it in turn to OpenSSL. NCSC-FI would like to thank
>   Codenomicon for reporting and analysing the vulnerability.

The heartbleed.com site is registered to Codenomicon

> Domain Name: HEARTBLEED.COM
>   Registrar URL: http://www.godaddy.com
>   Registrant Name: Marko Laakso
>   Registrant Organization: Codenomicon Oy

So going from what Matthew has said, it appears that the first public disclosure was either the [OpenSSL Security Advisory](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20140407.txt) or heartbleed.com, and the rest is history.

The Cloudflare blog post is 21 hours old at the present time, with the Hackernews post now at 20 hours old, so the initial announcements from OpenSSL / heartbleed.com are probably not much older than that.

---

Edit: heartbleed.com now states:

[OpenSSL Security Advisory](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20140407.txt) (published 7th of April 2014, ~17:30 UTC)
[Cloudflare Blog Entry](http://blog.cloudflare.com/staying-ahead-of-openssl-vulnerabilities) (published 7th of April 2014, ~18:00 UTC)
[heartbleed.com](http://heartbleed.com) (published 7th of April 2014, ~19:00 UTC)

Answer (score 1):

I was first alerted to this site Monday at 17:55 EST through a security discussion group. 
http://heartbleed.com/
The site has numerous references to info about the bug.